# Which NetBoot Server Am I Booted From?

Tags: network, startup, osx-server, netboot

Is there a way I can tell which NetBoot server a client machine has booted off of, from within the client machine itself?

This is kind of an obscure question, but I am in an environment that has two identical NetBoot servers. On the `Startup Disk` System Pref pane, each NetBoot 'volume' has the server IP address associated with it. But once the client has booted, is there a way I can determine which server it used/is using?

Comment: @Buscar This is a macOS question; ‘NetBoot is a technology from Apple which enables Macs with capable firmware to boot from a network’.

Comment: Does the information appear in Apple menu > About This Mac?

Comment: @Ashley Nope not anywhere I can see.